# How to disable some javascripts in magento multi sites

Tags: javascript, magento, magento-1.6

Having one issue:

We are having one store http://vinylshop.lt & now we done in the same platform multi site - http://ausines24.lt

And we are having some glitches with vinylshop.lt template JS (not working filter function in category) & ausines24.lt template JS (not working header-dropdown, search-dropdown, etc.), because both sites loading all platform's JS. Vinylshop.lt no need ausines24.lt JS & ausines24.lt no need vinylshop.lt JS.

Any solutions how to resolve this problem?

Many thanks for any suggestion/information!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have different themes you probably have different layout xmls, instead of importing the js globally you could just import it in the appropriate theme layout file.

Comment: Ok, understand, but how I can import just needed JS's for that theme?

I'm opened one theme layout.xml and I found that all needed JS's are coded in that file, but in conclusion when loading site, in source showing that loading both themes JS.

Comment: Like i said, import only the needed js files in your layout.xml from that theme. You probably set your js in the default folder instead of the themefolder layout.xml. Or you have set it in both, check the base/default folder and the default/default folder for those js files and throw them away. Or you could just use removeitem